# What do the status elements represent in SI File Transfer?

Tags: xmpp, smack

I'm trying to debug a larger issue I'm having with si file transfers not working on Linux, and noticed that my XML packets differ based on a status number within the `<si>` tag:

```
<iq from='foo@example.com/jid' 
    id='uid:00000000:00000000:00000000' 
    to='bar@example.com/Smack' 
    type='set' xml:lang='en'>
  <si notifyid='jsi_5724182428385442961'             
      profile='http://jabber.org/protocol/si/profile/file-transfer'          
      status='1039' 
      xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/si'
  />
</iq>
```

I've checked the [SI File Transfer spec](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0096.html), but haven't been able to find anything that details what the `status='1039'` detail actually means. Is there a document somewhere that details the differences in the various status codes and describes what they mean?

Comment: That does look like a properitary extension

Comment: Ah that might explain my confusion. I'll look in that direction.